# How to forbid own fonts for sites except specified ones?

Tags: firefox

I’d like to forbid usage of own fonts for all sites except several ones. Is there any add-on that can be of help? Couldn’t it be done with userContent.css somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice for a web developer to define the font-family specific in the CSS for their site. Usually these would be a serif font of some type. If the font-family is not defined then the default from the web browser's generic CSS file is used.

If it were me I would just use what the web developer has chosen. These fonts were probably specifically chosen due to the design of their web site. However your question was very vague...